# Cypress, get index of th element to use it later for it's td element

Tags: indexing, html-table, cypress

I have a question regarding Cypress. I have following table:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to get index of 'th' table element to get it's value in 'td'. I have tried it using jquery API but it returns for -1 instead 2:
Cypress.$('th:contains('Age')').index()

It doesn't need to be jquery> I just want to be sure that even if 'Age' changes it's position, I will be able to get it's corresponding correct value from 'td'.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's how you'd get the `index` of the column with the `Age` header:

```js
cy.contains('th', 'Age').invoke('index').then((i) => {
  console.log(i)
})
```

Comment: This isn't working with the latest - v12.3.0

Comment: Further explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d3SKQ-9WJI

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
        cy.document().then(document => {
            const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr th"));
            const getIndex = () => {
                for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
                    const element = elements[index];
                    if(element.innerText === "Age") {
                        return index;
                    }
                }
            }
            const theIndex = getIndex();
            console.log(theIndex);
        });
```

I'd create my own command like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getIndex", (text) => {
    return cy.document().then(document => {
        const elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tr th"));
        const getIndex = () => {
            for (let index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
                const element = elements[index];
                if(element.innerText === text) {
                    return index;
                }
            }
        }
        return getIndex();
    });
});
```

In your tests you can invoke it like this:

```js
cy.getIndex("Age").then(index => {
            console.log(index)
        })
```

Comment: This is not necessary, the original answer still works in Cypress 12 (an is much shorter!)