# Return value from nested wrap

Tags: cypress

I am starting out with cypress and I have a doubt about returning a value form a custom command.

I have multiple tables across my application, and in my tables I can click a row that will open a modal with more deailed information. So I want to build a command to extract the values of a specific row, so I can store them and then compare with the modal values.

I'm also trying to do this command in a way to reuse across the different tables. However I am having issues with my return value. This is my current command:

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'getRowInformation',
  (rowsSelector, compareValue, mainProperty, nestedSelector) => {
    let rowNumber = -1
    const propertiesObject = {}

    /** 
     * get all the field in the all the rows that might contain the compareValue
     */
    cy.get(`[data-testid="${mainProperty}"]`).then($elements => {
      cy.wrap($elements)
        .each(($elementField, index) => {
          /**
           * Find first match and get the row index
           */
          if (rowNumber === -1 && $elementField.text() === compareValue) {
            rowNumber = index + 1
          }
        })
        .then(() => {
          /**
           * Access needed row
           */
          rowsSelector()
            .eq(rowNumber)
            .within(() => {
              cy.get(nestedSelector).then($property => {
                cy.wrap($property)
                  .each($prop => {
                    Object.assign(propertiesObject, { [$prop.attr('data-testid')]: $prop.text() })
                  })
                  .then(() => {
                    /**
                     * Return key value map, where key in data-testid
                     * and value is the element's text
                     */
                    return cy.wrap(propertiesObject)
                  })
              })
            })
        })
    })
  },
)
```

And I am calling this command in my it() as:

```
cy.getRowInformation(myCustomSelector, 'Compare value', 'testid', 'span').then(properties => {
    console.log('properties', properties)
    expect(true).to.be.true
})
```

My custom selector:

```
myCustomSelector: () => cy.get('[data-testid="row"]'),
```

My problem is that what gets to my .then in my it() is the rowsSelector().eq(rowNumber) and what I needed is the created propertiesObject. From the docs I could not get an example as nested as this, so do you guys think this is doable?

Comment: I might be missing it. Are you returning anything from your custom command and all the nested `.then()` blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Yields-Icon-namequestion-circle) say `.within() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.`

So it seems you have to move your `cy.wrap(propertiesObject)` out of the within callback and put it in the outer `then`

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the issue I am facing. But if I move cy.wrap(propertiesObject) to the our then, won't this run before rowsSelector() 's method?

Comment: `cy.wrap` does not actually perform any computation and just stores the reference to `propertiesObject`. So I see no problem here.

Comment: Yeah, it was exactly this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also sub in `.find()` which is syntactically equivalent to `.within()`

```js
rowsSelector()
  .eq(rowNumber)
  .find(nestedSelector).each($prop => {
    Object.assign(propertiesObject, { [$prop.attr('data-testid')]: $prop.text() })
  })
  .then(() => cy.wrap(propertiesObject))
```

---

You might also want to review this [Cypress, get index of th element to use it later for it's td element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892945/16997707) for the section that finds the rowNumber.

I haven't tried it, but maybe

```js
cy.contains(`[data-testid="${mainProperty}"]`, compareValue)  // only 1st match returned
  .invoke('index')
  .then((rowNumber) => {
    rowsSelector()
      .eq(rowNumber)
      .find(nestedSelector)
      .each($prop => {
        Object.assign(propertiesObject, { [$prop.attr('data-testid')]: $prop.text() })
      })
      .then(() => cy.wrap(propertiesObject))
  })
```

Comment: Nice one, I will follow up with the invoke approach ^^