# Cypress - get value that is inside a component (into a variable)

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I'm a new developer and I am trying to build a certain test using cypress. the client has a dynamic grid, and I'd like to see which row in the grid contains the data I want. I cannot change the HTML file.

At the moment I am trying to iterate over all rows using each() cypress command. So I have two questions:

1. is this a correct approach?
2. assuming it is correct, how do I get the value out of the component? for example, how do I get the value of "aaaaaaaa" out of here (and into a variable):
   [html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gkyv8.png)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using each is a pretty good approach, select the rows and make use of the index parameter to find which one.

```js
cy.get('[role="row"]').each(($row, index) => {

  if ($row.find('span').text() === 'aaaa') {
    cy.wrap(index).as('rowIndex')
})

cy.get('@rowIndex')
  .then(rowIndex => {
    // use the row index here
  })
```

There's also this method [Cypress get index of th element to use it later](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50892945/16997707).

If it works (the jQuery docs don't show this usage) the code for your HTML would be

```js
cy.contains('[role="row"]', 'aaaa').invoke('index').as('rowIndex')

cy.get('@rowIndex')
  .then(rowIndex => {
    // use the row index here
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches you can take, but I think my preferred one is to store the variable in Cypress environment variable. In the following, I get the element, then use a `.then()` statement to get the text of the element (with the JQuery function, `.text()`), and store it in a Cypress environment variable (via `Cypress.env()`).

```js
describe('tests', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    cy.get('some-element').then(($el) => {
      Cypress.env('myVar', $el.text());
    })
    ... // some code
    // When needing the variable, reference it by Cypress.env('myVar');
   });

  afterEach(() => {
    // after each test, clear the variable
    Cypress.env('myVar', null)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a test doing the same thing and the way I've approached it was:

```
cy.contains('aaaa').invoke("text").as('variableName')
```

This can now be used like this:

```
cy.get(this.variableName).should('be.visible')

cy.contains('aaaa').parent().next().children() //Used to iterate through rows.
```